# Notifying the device immediately with push notification after the NFC transaction completed using Apple Pay

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, applepay, wallet, passkit

Can anyone shed some light on the Card Notification Service for Apple Pay.

The objective is , 
I want to receive push notification alert(showing the transaction details) to the device immediately after NFC transaction at POS.

The only thing I Know about this is, Apple is providing some APIs for the Card Notification services. I did some researches, But I couldn't find any relevant information regarding this.

Comment: I believe that this is something the card issuer handles on their back end, not part of Apple Pay

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the info. 

I also thought the same way, but for recieving the push notifications, it needs the device token right ?

Comment: Correct.  notifications can also be sent to wallet passes; cards are in the wallet.  If you tap on the notification it will open the card in your wallet with the details

Comment: Yes, You are right. This is something handled form the card issuer. 

Also heard that, If we are using Amex cards, the push notifications are coming but not for any other cards. 

Thanks again @Paulw11

Comment: I get push notifications from Amex for both Apple Pay and regular transactions while my other bank card only sends notifications for Apple Pay transactions, so it seems to depend on the issuer.

Comment: This discussion doesn't answer the question regarding the notificion API